# Are there any disadvantages of adding extra site columns directly to my List Content Type, instead of adding a new content type

Tags: 2013, list, development, content-type, app

I have added a new Issue tracking list , which is based on the build-in “Issue” content type. Then I need 5 extra columns to be used , so I did the following:-

1. I went to "Site setting">>"site columns", and I added 5 new site columns.
2. Then I went to my newly added list>>list setting>> Click on Issue content type, as follow:-

[image]

3. Then from their I chose to add from existing site columns, and I added the 5 new site columns, as follow:-

[image]

And everything worked well.
But I have the following 2 questions:-

1. Is adding site columns directly inside the default content type considered a good approach or it is considered a bad approach ? and I should create new content type, instead of extending the defualt content type at the list level?
2. Second question , why the site columns which I added inside the Issue list content type will have their source as blank, as follow? although they are site columns :-

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is

1. Create a new site content type (say `IssueTracking`) that is based on `Issue` content type
2. Add site columns to the new `IssueTracking` content type
3. Create new list. Edit List Settings. Advanced Setting. Add new content type and select `IssueTracking`
4. Make IssueTracking the default content type of the list and hide (the actual `Issue` from the list)

To answer your second question, the new columns you created are directly under the "edited list content type". Hence it has no source.

If you see `Title`, the source is `Item`. And `Title` is a site column that is part of Content Type `Item`.

Comment: but is my current approach wrong,, or i can keep the current settings as is ,, i mean what is the problem with my approach comparing to the other approach ?

Comment: Your approach is kind of isolated and hard to manage. If you follow the approach I suggested you can easily manage it in a central location. Also you can create new lists based on the central content type (no need to again add site columns etc.).

Comment: Read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrew_may/archive/2006/05/24/sharepointbeta2whatarecontenttypes.aspx which explains this very well

Comment: yes this is true but in my case i only need this list to be used once ... also when i create a custom content type and i create a new Create form based on the new custom content type, i lost the ability to hide and re-order columns through the list setting UI .. unlike using the defualt content type which will allow me to manage the columns order and visibility (Required,optional or hidden) inside the Create & edit forms from the content Type settings under the list settings UI...